# Possible to merge these two functions?

Tags: functions, taxonomy

I have these two functions.

The difference is that one is filtering custom taxonomy (is_tax) and the other is filtering generic WordPress tags (is_tag).

The work as I'd like them to be it seems that the code is being duplicated.

This is Taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sort_conference_by_date_tax' );
function sort_conference_by_date_tax( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
       if ( $query->is_tax() ) {
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');  
            $query->set('meta_key', 'start_date');  
            $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 
       }       
    }
}
```

This is for Tags (Standard WordPress)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sort_conference_by_date_tag' );
function sort_conference_by_date_tag( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
       if ( $query->is_tag() ) {
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');  
            $query->set('meta_key', 'start_date');  
            $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 
       }       
    }
}
```

I thought an array would work like this:

```
if ( $query->(array(('tag', 'tax'))) {
   return 0;
}
```

But it didn't seem to work for me...

I guess I am only doing something that would save a fraction of a second by merging these functions so if it can't be done prob best to just leave it alone right?

Thanks

Comment: This is essentially "How do I do an A or B check in PHP?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I would think you could just use an OR (||) operator to check if it `is_tag()` or `is_tax()`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sort_conference_by_date' );
function sort_conference_by_date( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
       if ( $query->is_tag() || $query->is_tax() ) {
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');  
            $query->set('meta_key', 'start_date');  
            $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 
       }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks VERY much - works really well....if more than anything it just keeps it neat and tidy

Comment: Glad to hear that worked out!